# regression on circular data

Tags: geometry, statistics, regression

How would one design a regression where the dependent variable is measured in degrees on a circle?

The dependent variable is on the range [0, 360), and the independent variables are demographic characteristics on each observation. The goal is to see how (or if) the independent variables affect the direction.  The basic problem is that 355 is closer to 5, than 5 is to 30.

Comment: By a regression, do you mean a "least-squares fit"?  Are you specifying that the best-fit curve should be periodic?  You may want to look into [LSSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_spectral_analysis).

Comment: @Omn I hope the edits answer your questions. I would not characterize the data as periodic, they're simply directions on a circle. I'm not married to least-squares, but I am looking for an approach that captures the contribution of each independent variable to the dependent variable.

Comment: You said that "the basic problem is that 355 is closer to 5 than 5 is to 30".  Presumably, this means that your best fit function $\hat y(x)$ should satisfy $\hat y(355)$ is closer to $\hat y (5)$ than $\hat y(30)$.  One way to force this behavior is to specify that $\hat y$ should be continuous and periodic with period $360$, i.e. that $\hat y(0)$ and $\hat y(360)$ should be the same.  That's where periodicity came in.

Comment: @Omn If periodicity is the hook to make this work, then I'm all for it. If the standard regression equation is $y=X\beta + \varepsilon$, where $y$ is on the range $[0,360)$ and $X$ is my matrix of demographic characteristics, how would you rewrite the equation to incorporate the periodicity?

Comment: I know I am a bit late to the party: Couln't you just use 360-periodic functions (like $x \mapsto cos(\pi/360 x)$) and apply your favourite regression method?

Answer (score 1):

You might think about orthogonal projection of the response vector
$$
y=\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\  \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix}
$$
onto the column space of the "design" matrix
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \cos\theta_1 & \sin\theta_1 \\  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\  1 & \cos\theta_n & \sin\theta_n \end{bmatrix}.
$$
The projection, which is the vector of fitted values, is $\hat y = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T y$.  The coefficients being estimated are the three components of the $3\times1$ matrix $\hat\beta=(X^T X)^{-1}X^T y$.

The most natural hypothesis test to do would probably be of the null hypothesis that the second and third components of $\beta$ are $0$.  I probably wouldn't even consider the two components *separately*, but only together.  The F-test would have $2$ degrees of freedom in the numerator and $n-3$ degrees of freedom in the denominator.  The F statistic would be
$$
F = \frac{\|\hat y - \bar y\mathbf 1_n\|^2/2}{\|y-\hat y\|^2/(n-3)}
$$
(where $\mathbf 1_n$ is an $n\times 1$ matrix in which every entry is $1$).

However, I my emend any of this after knowing something about your data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I hope the edits to the original question provide some clarification.